# Python- f.write() method deletes previous content of a text file

Tags: python, file, encryption, text, output

I decided to add text file reading and writing to a simple encryption program.

The idea being, that the program asks the user for two keys and an input, it encrypts them and saves them to a file.

When the user wants to retrieve the contents, the program asks for the two keys and reads from the file decrypting it.

So, I got that to work, once. The problem is, my program will ask the user 'Continue Y/N' after they encrypt. If they say yes and then ask for decryption it works fine. But if they ask to encrypt something else, it overwrites the previous content of the file.

This is most likely where the problem is, as it is where the reading and writing takes place.

```
def User_Text_Interface(Repeat):
    while Repeat == True:
        f = open("COT.txt", "w+")
        ED, Key, Key2, Temp = input("Do you want to encrypt or decrypt? "), input("Input a key- "), input("Input a second key- "), 0
        if ED.lower() =="encrypt" or ED.lower() == "e":
            User_Input =  input("Input a string to " + str(ED) + "- ")
        Key, Key2 = Compatibility(Key, User_Input), Compatibility(Key2,User_Input)
        if ED.lower() == "encrypt" or ED.lower() == "e":
            ET = str(Encrypt(User_Input, Key, Key2))
            f.write(ET + "\n")
            print("Your encrypted text is " + ET + " -it has been saved.")
        elif ED.lower() == "decrypt" or ED.lower() == "d":
            with open("COT.txt", "r+") as f:
                for line in f:
                    print(str(Decrypt(line, Key, Key2)))
        Repeat = input("Do you wish to continue? Y/N- ")
        if Repeat.lower() == "yes" or Repeat.lower() == "y":
            Repeat = True
        else:
            Repeat = False
```

For reference here is the rest of my code-

```
import time, sys, random
Master_Key = "0123456789 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!\"#£$%&'()*+,-./:;?@[\\]^_`{|}~"

 ## r+ means read and write


def Encrypt(User_Input, Key, Key2):
    Output = ""
    for i in range(len(User_Input)):
        Ref_For_Output = Master_Key.index(User_Input[i]) + Master_Key.index(Key[i]) + Master_Key.index(Key2[i])
        if Ref_For_Output >= len(Master_Key):     
            Ref_For_Output -= len(Master_Key)
        Output += Master_Key[Ref_For_Output]
    return Output 

def Decrypt(User_Input, Key, Key2):
    Output = ""
    for i in range(len(User_Input)):
        Ref_For_Output = Master_Key.index(User_Input[i]) - Master_Key.index(Key[i])- Master_Key.index(Key2[i])
        if Ref_For_Output < 0:
            Ref_For_Output += len(Master_Key)
        Output += Master_Key[Ref_For_Output]
    return Output

def Ordered_Test_Algorithm(Null):
    for i in range(len(Master_Key)-1): 
        Input= Master_Key[i]
        print("Input = " + Input)
        for i in range(len(Master_Key)-1):
            Key = Master_Key[i]
            for i in range(len(Master_Key)-1):
                Key2 = Master_Key[i]
                Output = Decrypt(Encrypt(Input, Key, Key2), Key, Key2)
                print("Encryption and decryption of Input- " + str(Input) + " with the Key- " + str(Key) + " and a second Key of " + str(Key2) + " results in an output of " + str(Output))
                if Input == Output:
                    print("Pass")
                else:
                    print("Fail")
                    sys.exit 
    print("Testing complete- Pass")
def Random_Test_Algorithm(Input_Length, Repeat_times):
    for i in range(Repeat_times): 
        User_Input, Key, Key2 = "", "", ""
        for i in range(Input_Length):
            Input_ref, Key_ref, Key_2_Ref = random.randint(0, len(Master_Key)-1), random.randint(0, (len(Master_Key)-1)), random.randint(0, (len(Master_Key)-1)) 
            User_Input += Master_Key[Input_ref]
            Key += Master_Key[Key_ref]
            Key2 += Master_Key[Key_2_Ref]
        print("The randomly generated " + str(Input_Length) + " character input key and second key are " + User_Input + ", " + Key + " and " + Key2 +" respectively.")
        print("The result of encryption is- " + Encrypt(User_Input, Key, Key2) )
        print("The result of decryption is- " + Decrypt(Encrypt(Input, Key, Key2), Key, Key2) ) 
        if User_Input == Decrypt(Encrypt(Input, Key, Key2), Key, Key2):
            print("The encryption and decryption of " + User_Input + " with " + Key + " and " + Key2 + " was successful")
        else:
            print("The encryption and decryption of " + User_Input + " with " + Key + " and " + Key2 + " was un-successful")
            sys.exit

def Compatibility(Key, User_Input):
    Temp = 0
    while Key == "":
            print("Your key cannot be blank")
    while len(Key) > len(User_Input): 
            Key = Key[:-1]
    while len(Key) < len(User_Input): 
            Key += (Key[Temp]) 
            Temp += 1
    return Key

def User_Text_Interface(Repeat):
    while Repeat == True:
        f = open("COT.txt", "w+")
        ED, Key, Key2, Temp = input("Do you want to encrypt or decrypt? "), input("Input a key- "), input("Input a second key- "), 0
        if ED.lower() =="encrypt" or ED.lower() == "e":
            User_Input =  input("Input a string to " + str(ED) + "- ")
        Key, Key2 = Compatibility(Key, User_Input), Compatibility(Key2,User_Input)
        if ED.lower() == "encrypt" or ED.lower() == "e":
            ET = str(Encrypt(User_Input, Key, Key2))
            f.write(ET + "\n")
            print("Your encrypted text is " + ET + " -it has been saved.")
        elif ED.lower() == "decrypt" or ED.lower() == "d":
            with open("COT.txt", "r+") as f:
                for line in f:
                    print(str(Decrypt(line, Key, Key2)))
        Repeat = input("Do you wish to continue? Y/N- ")
        if Repeat.lower() == "yes" or Repeat.lower() == "y":
            Repeat = True
        else:
            Repeat = False 

print("This program can run three different sub-programs-")
print("1- Run the encryption and decryption sub-program specified in Unit A453- CAM 3.")
print("2- Run a test which encrypts and decrypts each ascii character with each other ascii character.")
print("3- Run a test which generates random inputs and keywords, before encrypting and decrypting them.")
Option = input("Please choose either 1, 2 or 3- ")
if Option == "1":
    print("Running text based program-")
    time.sleep(1)
    User_Text_Interface(True)
elif Option == "2":
    print("This test will encrypt and decrypt each keyboard character with every other keyboard character")
    print("It will print around 1,860,000 lines of output, unless a decrypted value is not equal to its input, this will cause the test to stop")
    print("Beginning test- ")
    Ordered_Test_Algorithm("Null")
    time.sleep(1)
elif Option == "3":
    print("This test will generate a random input and keyword of a specified length using the random.randint function in the random module.")
    print("It will then encrypt and decrypt the input with the keyword before checking if the output is equal to the input.")
    print("The test will repeat a specifieed number of times.")
    Input_Length = int(input("Input a numerical length (Length in characters e.g. 'Python' is 6 characters)for the key and keyword- "))
    Repeat_times = int(input("Input the number of times the test should be repeated- "))
    print("Beginning test- ")
    time.sleep(1)
    Random_Test_Algorithm(Input_Length, Repeat_times)
```

Note that there is no real error, the program writes a .txt file named COT.txt which stands for something output text. I honestly can't remember what the c stands for.

Anyway that is what I intended it to do, but I wanted it to write each new line of encrypted text to a new line of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f = open("COT.txt", "w+")
```

Write mode overwriting the file, you have to open it in `a+` mode;

```
f = open("COT.txt", "a+")
```

Or just use `with open()` method which is way better.

```
with open("COT.txt","a+") as f:
    f.write(something)
```

Comment: I what way is it better? At the beginning of my User|_Text_Interface function I used open() anyway, and then I can just use f.write() throughout the rest of the function.

Comment: @TheoPearson-Bray You don't have to care about closing your file with `with open()` method. It's safier and more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `a+` file mode which appends to the contents rather than overwriting like `w+`.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe it was that simple. Shame on me.